# Displaying PDF browser different result Firefox/Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, pdf

I'm creating a little website, and I'm having some difficulties to display a PDF in it.
The PDFs are store in a folder called "biography".

I have a drop-down menu like this :

```
<option value="Cat">Cat</option>
<option value="Dog">Dog</option>
```

And a JavaScript function that will search for the PDF with the exact name and display it.

```
            <script>
            function affichage(value){
              pdf=document.getElementById('pdf');
              pdf.setAttribute("src", "biography/"+value+".pdf");
            }
            </script>
```

And i embed it using :

```
<embed id="pdf" width="100%" height="1330"></embed>
```

My problem is that even tough it works with Firefox, the PDF's are not displayed using Chrome and I can't see why.

Is there maybe a more proper way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Use google document viewer

```
https://docs.google.com/viewer?embedded=true&url=YOUR_URL_TO_DOCUMENT
```

Embed this using iframe tag